# Is "Трудно быть богом?" (as in the title of the book) a valid question in written or formal Russian?

Tags: литература

Prompted by our [*Hard to Be a God* book challenge](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/650/11)<sup>1</sup> on [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), we've been trying to gather some attention by posting to relevant chat rooms.

An interesting discussion sparked in the Russian Stack Overflow chat: a user mentioned that it is ambiguous whether the original title of the book (*Трудно быть богом*) is a question or a statement.

[I replied](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36413071#36413071) that this form is most often used for statements, and is unlikely to be used as a question (to be clear, **we're discussing the phrase now, not the book title**); however, it occurred to me that this could be used as a question in spoken language, similar to `Болит нога?`.

I [do know](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36413163#36413163) that it requires a question mark at the end to be a real question, and I do know `трудно ли быть богом?` is much better. **For the record**, Russian is my mother tongue. However, I don't have much experience with formal texts (haven't studied Russian since 7th grade).

My main concern is - **can this form of a question be used in formal or written Russian? How acceptable is it?**

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: **Everyone is welcome to participate! Ask your *Hard to be a God* questions, and post good answers to others' questions!**</sub>

Comment: The book's title is a citation from the book itself, where it's an undoubtedly affirmative sentence.

Answer (score 6):

In (written) Russian, any statement can be turned to question by adding the question mark. So, `Трудно быть богом?` is a correct question. `Трудно быть богом.` is a statement.  In book names, the period is often omitted, so if a book is called `Трудно быть богом` without the question mark, it is a statement.

Частица `ли` (as in the question `Трудно ли быть богом?`) is not required in direct questions, but without it, the style would be colloquial/informal rather than formal.  (In indirect questions like `Она спросила его, трудно ли быть богом.` it is required).

Summary:

- `Трудно быть богом` (book name) - statement
- `Трудно быть богом?` (book name) - question
- `Трудно быть богом.` - statement.
- `Трудно быть богом?` - question, informal style
- `Трудно ли быть богом?` - question, formal style
- `Она спросила его, трудно быть богом.` - incorrect
- `Она спросила его, трудно ли быть богом.` - correct statement, which contains indirect question

Answer (score 4):

This form can be a question only if it is followed by an explicit question mark: "Трудно быть богом?"

Otherwise, it is hardly perceived as a question, since the more usual form would include a particle: "Трудно **ли** быть богом?", but the orignal title has no question mark, therefore, it can't be construed as a question.

Impersonal statement like that can't be formal.  To make it formal you need an addressee:

"Трудно **ли вам/ему/ей** быть богом?" — and you need "ли" as well.

Answer (score 2):

First, *Трудно быть богом* is a statement, not a question unless finalized with a question mark.

As for your question - this form is quite acceptable but a bit informal. If used in scientific articles for example, *Трудно **ли** быть богом* is more preferable. Especially in indirect speech:

> Трудно ли быть богом? (title)    **CORRECT, FORMAL**
>
> Быть богом – трудно. (title)    **CORRECT, FORMAL**
>
> Трудно быть богом? (title)    **INCORRECT**
>
> Она спросила его, трудно ли быть богом.    **CORRECT, FORMAL**
>
> Она спросила, трудно ли ему быть богом.    **CORRECT, FORMAL**
>
> Она спросила его, насколько трудно быть богом.    **CORRECT, FORMAL**
>
> Она спросила его: «Трудно быть богом?»    **OK, INFORMAL/ARTISTIC**
>
> Она спросила его, трудно быть богом.    **INCORRECT**

Comment: Question-ending titles are also acceptable, to the best of my knowledge